# Upgrade to Backpack 4.0 causes view problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I could use any insight you might have on this. I've updated my site from Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 5.8, and have updated Backpack to v4.0. I'm having an issue with my admin panel pages not showing correctly.

The dashboard is showing the view from `resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/src/resources/views/layout.blade.php` - which uses `<body class="hold-transition {{ config('backpack.base.skin') }} sidebar-mini">`

[screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgXhQ.png)

The CRUD pages are showing the view from `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/layouts/top_left.blade.php` - which uses `<body class="{{ config('backpack.base.body_class') }}">`
This isn't loading the correct theme and things are piled on top of one another.

[screenshot of crud page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWp2o.png)

Can anyone tell me why I have two different views going on in these packages? I deleted these package folders and used `composer update` to reload everything but it's still showing the same thing. I'm wondering if I have something incorrect in my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0",
        "backpack/crud": "^4.0.0",
        "backpack/permissionmanager": "^5.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "1.5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "backpack/generators": "1.2.*",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "laracasts/generators": "dev-master",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you probably missed the step to re-publish backpack assets and are loading the old ones.

Also if you have overriden backpack views (fields, columns etc) you should update them to use the latest syntax (BP v4.0++)

Let me know,